# Using Racket ISL to create a function using a foldr list abstraction

Tags: racket

How can I rewrite the total-pages function below in order to just use the foldr function rather than using foldr and map list abstractions (since using foldr and map requires going over the list twice, which is less efficient than going over the list once)?

```
(define (total-pages lorp)
  (foldr + 0
         (map num-pages lorp)))

(define (num-pages rp)
  (+ 1
     (-
      (page-end rp)
      (page-start rp))]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I'll show you the solution, some notes for the next time:

- Add please all needed definitions and used libraries. `page-end` and `page-start` aren't defined.
- Use names better than `lorp` and `rp` or explain the meaning of these names.

You have to write `num-pages` inside `foldr` function like this:

```
(define (total-pages lorp)
  (foldr (lambda (element result)
           (+ result (num-pages element)))
         0
         lorp))

(define (num-pages rp)
  (+ 1
     (-
      (page-end rp)
      (page-start rp))))
```

**EDIT:** Move the body of `lambda` into a new function:

```
(define (num-pages rp)
  (add1
     (-
      (page-end rp)
      (page-start rp))))

(define (add-pages element result)
  (+ result (num-pages element)))

(define (total-pages lorp)
  (foldr add-pages
         0
         lorp))
```

Comment: I cannot use the lambda function in my total-pages function.